# Android Gallery is conditionally using .nomedia

Tags: gallery

Using stock Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), the stock (LG V10) gallery application (version 4.72.6) is including pictures and other files that have a timestamp newer than the .nomedia file timestamp. I have not been able to test this on other devices to see if it is LG specific.

Recreating the .nomedia file will update the timestamp, and hide all older pictures. Also, the folder being index is a hidden one (starts with a '.'), not sure why it is also being indexed in the first place.

There seem to be a lot of topics on this indexing issue, but none associated with the timestamps. It appears this could have been done intentionally, but it is very undesirable since several applications cannot access the microSD card after the Android permissions update.

Comment: This does not appear to be brand specific. I tested this on another device using Cyanogenmod 13, based on Android version 6.0.1. The pattern is the same which leads me to believe this is an intentional android "feature". 
Anyone have any suggestions on a workaround for this?

Comment: This is because the information is already stored in Media Storage database, it should eventually clear itself out (possibly with a reboot), but the easiest fix would be to to go Apps and find Media Storage (may have to enable System apps view) and clear data on that and reboot.

Comment: I thought that too, but it is not the case. Newly created images show up, even if the folder has had the .nomedia file in it for days before hand.